# Set Ajax response on jsp not working

Tags: java, javascript, html

Last few hours i am trying to solve this but i can not.I am sending ajax request using jquery and based on response i set data on jsp.actully i am checking login detail so if login fail it set error message on label problem is that error message is set for few second and removed i mean to say error message is set for few second i want that if login fails the message is set on label still user enter valid details

thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
         LoginDemo.jsp

      <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="css/firstpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- <style> -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){   
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddInspServlet",
    cache:false,
    data: { userid: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val(),btn:$('#submit').val() },
     success:function(data,textstaus){
     alert("success:"+data);     
     if(data == "no"){       
        alert( document.getElementById("error").innerHTML);     
         document.getElementById("error").innerHTML= "UserName OR Password is  incorrect";
        alert( document.getElementById("error").innerHTML);

  }else{
      location.href = 'Home.jsp';

  }

   },
   error:function(data){
    alert("error"+data);
     },  
    });
    });
    });

  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <form id="login" name="Loginform" method="post">
     <h1><b>Log In</b></h1>
       <fieldset id="inputs">
       <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>   
       <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </fieldset>
     <fieldset id="actions">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="login">
      <a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
     </fieldset>
   <label id="error" style="color: red;font: bolder; font-size: 18px;"> 
   </label>
  </form>
</body>
```

```
      AddInspServlet
```

Here i m adding code which server executed and retrieve response

```
   if(btn.equals("login"))
     {
    System.out.println("***** login condition checking ******");
    String password =request.getParameter("password");
    UserVO v =op.loginCheck(username, password);
    if(password.equals(v.getPassword()))
    {
        System.out.println("inside true condition");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("userid",v.getUser_id());
        session.setAttribute("username",v.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("user", v.getFirst_name()+" "+v.getLast_name());
        session.setAttribute("roleid", v.getRole_id());
      //  response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
        System.out.println("submitting data success fully");
        out.print("yes");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("false condition");
        out.print("no");
       }
     }
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your concern. Could you be more specific where you are getting problem?

Comment: You can use setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = ""}, 2000); for removing error message after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `form` tags.

By adding a `type="submit" input` element without using the `action` attribute in the `form` tag, the page will be reloaded.

Or you could keep the `form` tags and change the type of the `submit` button to `type="button"`. The form will then not be executed and the page will not reload.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you be more specific about the problem. I assume your problem is Label is getting displayed for few seconds and then get disappeared. Is that is true? then try to return "false" inside you data == "no" logic.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you are right probelm is like that and i already apply that retuen false but its not working